# What's wrong with my SRV record?

Tags: dns

So, I've managed to make up and running my dns services. 
One of my goals was to create and test the SRV records for minecraft but it doesn't seem to work.

So first question is maybe : does minecraft still look for srv records on the connecting domain? 
**Statements:**

- The server is reachable by the same adress + port number.
- The server bind9 under Ubuntu doesn't declare any error about my syntax in the file.
- The minecraft server is behind a NAT but like I said it's
  reachable

So I will put here what I think is relevant  in my dns file:

```
...
mc IN A 91.183.0.55
...
_minecraft._tcp.mc.vigilian-consulting.com. SRV 0 5 45433 mc.vigilian-consulting.com.
```

Did I forget anything? Did I do something wrong? Is it a problem from the other part of the dns? then if it is tell me that I Can put it here.
I've red [another post](https://serverfault.com/questions/474225/minecraft-dns-srv-record-correct-setup) on SRV record here but it's absolutely not the same syntax for the dns server and didn't help me a lot. 
the [dnsinspect](http://www.dnsinspect.com/vigilian-consulting.com/10020518) sounds good to me 
Is it a problem that the `nslookup` command tells that this is not an authorative server? Is it because of that it hasn't any key yet?

Comment: Does the value show up correctly when you *query* for it with a DNS client?

Comment: well I have a good answer like that: 
`nslookup -querytype=srv _minecraft._tcp.mc.example.com
Server:  dnsadaprim.example.com
Address:  192.168.5.3

_minecraft._tcp.mc.example.com      SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 5
          port           = 45433
          svr hostname   = mc.example.com
example.com nameserver = ns1.example.com
example.com nameserver = ns2.example.com
mc.example.com      internet address = publicipadress`

Comment: It is easier if you provide us with the domain name = we can do some troubleshooting + you can also get some extra players on your server

Comment: okey okey I will modify my post then but it was to not put more garbage information.

Comment: SRV record does look correct together with the A-record. I suspecting that the minecraft client is having issues resolving/using it

Comment: okey so maybe more a dev issue from minecraft than something else. I was afraid that it would be my fault so if it is not it's okey then. thanks anyway